# Matrix multiplication commutative property

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Let A=(I-S)(I+S), can it be written as A=(I+S)(I-S) where I is identity matrix and S is n rowed real skew symmetric matrix? I have a question and in solution they wrote it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes: $I$ is in the centre of ring of $n\times n$ matrices, and $S$ makes no difficulty to commute with itself.

Comment: Yes, because all matrices involved commute with each other. or just because $(I+S)(I-S) = I^2 + SI -IS - SS = I - SS$ and $(I-S)(I+S) = I^2 -SI + IS - SS = I - S^2$.

Comment: I got it, Thanks!